# fetch from json file (Python)

Tags: python, json

```
x = json.load(open('Download.json'))
for sub_dict in x['result']:
    print('model', sub_dict["model"])
    for entry in sub_dict['model']:
        print(entry['downloadSize'])
```

Error:

```
    print(entry['downloadSize'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I can not get the value of `downloadurl` in any way. How to contact him correctly?

json structure attached in images

[json structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT2nP.png)
[json structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nFFs.png)

Comment: please write json here.

Comment: try to print `entry` & Check its datatype.

Comment: entry is a string .... it is the keys of the sub_dict ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = json.load(open('Download.json'))
for sub_dict in x['result']:
    print('model', sub_dict["model"])
    print(sub_dict['model']['downloadSize'])
```

sub_dict['model'] is a dictionary not a list

so when you do `for entry in sub_dict['model']` that is the same as

`for key in sub_dict['model'].keys()`  each "entry" in that iteration is just a string that is a key to the sub_dict['model'] dictionary